# ssrs report affected by server settings

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 servers that im testing a report on, the ssrs report is identical on both servers, and it calls the same stored procedures, however one report is duplicating sections and the other is not. Im running both reports in the same version of IE. Are there setting or updates on the servers that could affect the reports display?

Comment: Do the stored procedures manipulate the data at all, or use temp tables?

Comment: Are the stored procedures identical? Are you running the same version of SQL Server on both servers?

Comment: The stored procedures are identical, not sure on the sql server versions but I can check, can the server version affect the display and cause sections to repeat on one server and not the other?